# How to write a function for editing a file and then running a command?

Tags: files

I would like to write a function that does the equivalent of the shell command:

```
vim $MY_FILE && $MY_COMMAND
```

In other words, I would like to open a file in a buffer, and then when I save/close that buffer, I want it to run a certain shell command. How would I do this?

Furthermore, the shell command must be run in `su` mode, so I need to either run it in an interactive shell so that the `sudo` mode prompts for the password, or maybe have a popup that asks for the superuser password somehow.

Comment: Just use **`after-save-hook`**: `C-h v after-save-hook`.

Comment: @Drew Is there a function equivalent of `C-h v`? I'm writing a function, not looking for a key combination.

Comment: @sid-kap `C-h v after-save-hook RET` will give you the documentation for the variable `after-save-hook`, which is what @Drew suggests you use. You can add a hook with `(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'my-function)` or `(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda () ...))`.

Comment: @sid-kap See also variable `kill-buffer-hook`.